# How to control node positions in GraphViz

Tags: graph, tree, graphviz

I have the following Graph [Link](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1463118481747#digraph%20G%20%7B%0Adir%3D%22back%22%3B%0Af00%20-%3E%20f10%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af00%20-%3E%20f11%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af10%20-%3E%20f20%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af10%20-%3E%20f22%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af11%20-%3E%20f21%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af11%20-%3E%20f23%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0A%7D)

I would like to make the last row as  f20 f21 f22 f23 so that the edges f21-f11 and f22-f10 cross each other. Basically this tree will grow even more downwards and I need to have all the nodes in same rank ordered (f20 f21 f22 f23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve [the desired result](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1463122883260#digraph%20G%20%7B%0Adir%3D%22back%22%3B%0Af00%20-%3E%20f10%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af00%20-%3E%20f11%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af10%20-%3E%20f20%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af11%20-%3E%20f22%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af10%20-%3E%20f21%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af10%20-%3E%20f22%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af11%20-%3E%20f21%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af11%20-%3E%20f23%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0A%7D) by using a combination of

- **invisible edges** and
- edges with **`constraint=false`**

I added `constraint=false` to the edges which should be crossing in order to not have them influence the layout. Then 2 more invisible edges were needed to have the layout engine place the nodes in the right place - `f21` should be under `f10`, and `f22` under `f11`.

```
digraph G {
  dir="back";
  f00 -> f10[dir="back"];
  f00 -> f11[dir="back"];
  f10 -> f20[dir="back"];

  // invisible edges for the layout
  f11 -> f22[style=invis];
  f10 -> f21[style=invis];

  // crossing edges without constraint
  f10 -> f22[dir="back", constraint=false];
  f11 -> f21[dir="back", constraint=false];

  f11 -> f23[dir="back"];
}
```

Comment: For large results, how do I prevent this?  tinyurl.com/gvizavn

Comment: You can always be explicit and constrain nodes to the same rank tinyurl.com/he7ynkh